# How can I produce a percentage barchart in R groupping by specific group?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a table like this in R:

```
Name Column2 Counts
Jason Disease 5
Jason NonDisease 6
Jason Iduced 7
Giacomo Disease 2
Giacomo NonDisease 2
Giacomo Induced 6
```

And I would like to procude a plot similar to this
But Instead having the "Day" I would like to have the name and Instead having the "Sex" I would group according to Disease and Compute the percentage of the Counts grouping By Column 3 of the dataframe, So for example I Would Like to have 2 bar called Jason and Giacomo (Instead the name of the Day) with the percentage computed withrespect to the third column, for example Jason, Disease = 5/(5+6+7), Giacomo Disease, 2/(2+2+6) and so on for other Condition in other grid (instead of Sex) (So same computation for NonDisease and Induces).
[image]

In Order to produce the plot above I have used this following code and dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
data(tips, package = "reshape2")

  ggplot(tips, aes(x= day,  group=sex)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), stat="count") +
  geom_text(aes( label = scales::percent(..prop..),
                 y= ..prop.. ), stat= "count", vjust = -.5) +
  labs(y = "Percent", fill="day") +
  facet_grid(~sex) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Comment: Can you share your data (use dput(data) to get a nice printout) and code? It should generally be a matter of changing a few parameters in ggplot around so you're grouping by different variables, but having the code you have compiled for your current result will make it easier to assist you.

Comment: @CareyCaginalp I have added the code needed to download the dateset and produce the plot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, the data doesn't completely match your example but I believe what you are getting at is how to switch around which variable is broken out into groups and which one is faceted. You can change them around in the `x` and `group` aesthetics, as well as the variable inside `facet_grid` to make whatever combination you might like. For example, to show male/female on each day you could use this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
data(tips, package = "reshape2")

ggplot(tips, aes(x= sex,  group=day)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..prop.., fill = factor(..x..)), stat="count") +
  geom_text(aes( label = scales::percent(..prop..),
                 y= ..prop.. ), stat= "count", vjust = -.5) +
  labs(y = "Percent", fill="sex") +
  facet_grid(~day) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Result:

[image: Resulting image]

Comment: Thank you @CareyCaginalp

Answer (score 1):

as much as I understood let me just reproduce the code

```
name <- c("Jason","Jason","Jason","giamco","giamco","giamco")
disease <- c("Disease","NonDisease","Iduced","Disease","NonDisease","Iduced")
Counts <- c(5,6,7,2,2,6)
df <- data.frame(name,disease,Counts)
```

This code will produce your requirement:

```
df %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(sum_num = sum(Counts)) %>% ggplot(aes(x = name, y = 
Counts, fill = disease))+geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = position_dodge(width = 
0.9))+geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(Counts/sum_num * 100,0),"%")), position = 
position_dodge(width = 0.9),vjust = -0.9)
```

Result:

[image: Graph]